# Edit This - Plugin Help

Tags: ee2

I've just installed the Edit This 2.1 plugin by Travis Smith (Hop Studios)

I'm on ExpressionEngine v2.7.2.

Here's the documentation for reference : [Plugin Documentation](http://www.hopstudios.com/software/edit_this/docs#Installation%20for%20EE%202.x)

I have inserted this tag within my channel entries.

```
{exp:edit_this:entry entry_id="{entry_id}" channel_id="{channel_id}" author_id="{author_id}"}
```

The little pencil icon is appearing, which is great. However the problem is when I click the icon it opens in a new tab and tells me to login when I'm already logged in. It should just go to the form to edit the entry.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you initially logging-in via the control panel, or via a login form on your public site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that "http://domain.com" is not the same as "http://www.domain.com" to ExpressionEngine. You are logged into the CP using one URL and EditThis is sending you to the other.

This fix this, you need to set a "Cookie Domain" on the [**Cookie Settings page**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/cookie_settings.html).

> **FROM THE DOCS:**
>
> This preference allows you to set your cookie domain. The vast majority of people will want to set this to:
>
> .example.com
>
> Obviously you’ll use your actual domain name instead of ”.example.com”. Note the period at the beginning as it is very important. Setting the cookie domain like this will allow the cookies to work regardless of whether people specify your URL with the www part or only the http:// part.
>
> If you want to restrict your cookies to a single subdomain then you may set that here as well:
>
> .subdomain.example.com